# Mobile Internet Modem Olivetti Olicard 155 does not work in Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: usb-modem, modem, 3g, modem-manager

I have a problem, I bought a 3G mobile modem, but does not work in Ubuntu 12.10, also did not work on Ubuntu 12.04.

I installed the USB Modeswitch and has the same flaw, does not recognize the modem within the connection manager, I connect the modem to the USB port and wait up to 20 minutes and does not recognize the modem.

I ran the command recognizes the modem and lsusb as "Bus 001 Device 007: ID 0b3c: C004 Olivetti TechCenter."

Does anyone have this modem, you can help me solve the problem, or does anyone have a solution? Because the manufacturer does not support Linux and according to some forums usbmodeswitch supports esste model.

Olivetti Olicard modem 155.

Answer (score 2):

**Tested on my Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS PC:**

- First, **add the following lines** to the `/etc/udev/rules.d/14-olicardmodules.rules` file (you will need superuser privileges to edit it):

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="0b3c",ATTRS{idProduct}=="c004",RUN+="/sbin/modprobe usbserial vendor=0x0b3c product=0xc004"
KERNEL=="ttyUSB[23]",ACTION==”add”,ATTRS{idVendor}=="0b3c",ATTRS{idProduct}=="c004",RUN+ ="/bin/sleep 6"
```

[Source](http://linuxnomicro.blogspot.com.br/2012/03/modem-olivetti-olicard-155-no-ubuntu.html) (in Portuguese)

- Now **remove the USB modem** and reattach it (no reboot was needed in my case). It might take a while, but a new entry will show up on the list of network connections as "Mobile Broadband". Click "enable mobile broadband", a checkmark will appear next to it:

[image]

- You have successfully enabled mobile broadband networking, but you still need to **set up the connection settings** as per your ISP parameters. In order to do that, <del>call your ISP tech support call center and get ready for long hours of waiting, because the tech support drones can't tell their left hand from the right and will enter kernel panic mode when you mention "Linux"</del>.
- Just kidding. Click "edit connections", and on the "mobile broadband" tab click "add". Follow the dialog boxes filling your country and carrier names, and Ubuntu will provide the connection settings itself! No need for fiddling with settings, contacting tech support or installing third-party drivers. *Ain't it beautiful*?

[image]

Comment: @kokbira Android is out of scope for this site. Try [Android.se]